# Bug in commenting user from list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

On this Answer: [Read HP Basic (RMB) tokenized file into clear text?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11728/6868)

When I add a comment with `@nick` I can see the usual list of users to pick from and there the `Staffan` user is twice. Its probably due to fact (s)he is the autor of both the Question and Answer.

Hard to say if it should be considered a bug or not but its a bit confusing so here it is ...

[image: duplicate user entry]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different Staffans. This occasionally happens when a user registers an account part-way through using the site, if the cookie magic fails to connect the unregistered account to the newly-created registered one. (In this case, given that both accounts have been posting comments, I suspect it might be caused by using Retrocomputing on two different devices.)

In such a case, [see the Help Center](/help/merging-accounts):

> ### I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
>
> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

I've suggested this to the user in question.

Comment: thx for reply ... now it makes sense